# Plugin Breaking Wordpress Login

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, fatal-error

Two issues with this plugin, please help...

1 My plugin is breaking my /wp-admin to where all I get is a white screen instead of forwarding to the login screen, which is also broken when this is enabled.  The rest of the site works.

2 Another problem with my plugin is that I can't get it to echo back the files in that directory. There are two files in there styles.css and new.css.  I've used this method to display files in a folder before but I can't get it to work here.

```
<?php
 /*
Plugin Name: Call Custom CSS
Description: Call custom CSS files to your theme while still being to recieve theme development updates
Version: 1.1.0
Author: Michele Narup
Author URI: http://michelenarup.com
*/

function addcss(){
$directory = get_site_url() . "/wp-content/css/";
$stylesheets = glob($directory . "*.css");

wp_enqueue_style('styles' , get_site_url(). '/wp-content/css/style.css');
//echo $directory;
    foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet)
    { 
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet'";
    echo $stylesheet;
    echo "type='text/css' media='all' />";
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addcss');

 ?>
```

As per a discussion in the comments below I changed the function to now read:

```
 /*
Plugin Name: Call Custom CSS
Description: Call custom CSS files to your theme while still being to receive theme development updates
Version: 1.1.0
Author: Michele Narup
Author URI: http://michelenarup.com
*/


function load_my_style () {
wp_register_style('customstyle', get_site_url() . '/wp-content/css/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_style');
```

This works but does not fix the white screen problem.  /wp-admin is still not rendering anything at all on the page or page source.  Also note, problem #2 is now irrelevant based on the new function, I will revisit that later. For now I'm focusing on getting the login screen to work.

Comment: That is not the way to add stylesheets in WordPress. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113127/21376 (among numerous other questions). Second, do you know which line causes the error? [Do you have debugging information?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: I don't want to add it through the functions or within the template directory since the Theme is not mine and I want to be able to still get maintenance updates without messing up my css changes.

Comment: There is no error, it is simply a solid white page when it loads the /wp-admin

Comment: Never said to add the stlyesheet through the theme or `functions.php`. Plugins can add stylesheets through the same, and appropriate, mechanisms. A white screen usually indicates an error whether you see the error or not. Follow my debugging link.

Comment: Ok, there are a lot of errors coming up from other plugins... But this is the only line from the plugin I wrote `[30-Jan-2014 19:38:10] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /____/____/public_html/____/wp-content/plugins/call-css/call-css.php:26) in /____/____/public_html/____/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896`

Comment: Which line is that?

Comment: `header("Location: $location", true, $status);`  Also, I changed the css to call in the way you suggested.  Did not effect the white screen but its being called in correctly.

Comment: Cannot modify header information often occurs when you have white space before the opening php tag, or after the closing php tag. Also, a "warning" shouldn't cause white screen of death.

Comment: @helgatheviking OMG! you are amazing! That fixed it, there was a return after the closing tag! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Cannot modify header information, headers already sent" often occurs when you have white space before the opening php tag, or after the closing php tag.